# Hover effect for elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to add CSS to all `li` elements on `mouseover` event except the hovered one, which should be faded?

CSS:

```
.tile_nav { width:241px; list-style:none;}
.tile_nav li { width:60px; height:60px; float:left;
 list-style:none; background:#ccc; margin:0 1px 1px 0;}
.tile_nav li a { width:60px; height:60px; display:block;}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tile_nav li").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css("opacity", ".5");
    });
    $(".tile_nav li").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css("opacity", "1");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="tile_nav">
    <li><a href="#">Tile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tile</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You did almost correctly.
Just using siblings you need to do.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tile_nav li").mouseover(function() {
       $(this).siblings().css("opacity", .5);
    });
    $(".tile_nav li").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).siblings().css("opacity", 1);
    });
});
```

Comment: how to avoid that affecting sub <ul> li items ? eg: <ul><li></li><ul class="sub"><li></li></ul></ul> tried $(".tile_nav > li") its not working.

Comment: // use like this
$(".tile_nav").children('li')
This will not be affected for sub menus

Comment: sorry i m wrong here..
The below code should work.. try it
$(this).siblings('li').css("opacity", .5);
 $(this).siblings('li').css("opacity", 1);

Comment: I have checked in your js fiddle..
Above code works fine..
let me know if you have any difficulties

Comment: how to avoid this affecting to sub ul li elements? https://jsfiddle.net/id10922606/8qkt6b07/2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80666/discussion-between-selvakumar-and-user3927335).

Comment: Thank you selva. this s ok. but second level ul li not required opacity change on over of second level li elements.  opacity change only required first level li elements

Answer (score 0):

You can .siblings() to style the sibling li elements

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tile_nav li").hover(function () {
        $(this).siblings().css("opacity", .5);
    }, function () {
        $(this).siblings().css("opacity", 1);
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tile_nav li").hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings().css("opacity", .5);
  }, function() {
    $(this).siblings().css("opacity", 1);
  });
});
```

```css
.tile_nav {
  width: 241px;
  list-style: none;
}
.tile_nav li {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
.tile_nav li a {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tile_nav">
  <li><a href="#">Tile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tile</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks. this is working fine. but when we use <ul><li></li><ul class="sub"><li></li></ul></ul>  that won't affect. pls help

Comment: @user3927335 can you edit the fiddle to recreate the case

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use this code
css:
 #all > ul {
            list-style: none;
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            padding: 0 10px 0 0;
        }

        #all a {
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            background: #900;
            border-radius: 20px;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 0 5px 0;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        }

        #all:hover a {
            opacity: 0.2;
        }

        #all:hover ul:hover a {
            opacity: 0.5;
        }

            #all:hover ul:hover a:hover {
                opacity: 1;
            }

html:
<div id="page-wrap">

        <div id="all">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">---</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

jquery :
$("#all ul li").hover(function() { // Mouse over
  $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(300, 0.6);
  $(this).parent().siblings().stop().fadeTo(300, 0.3); 
}, function() { // Mouse out
  $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(300, 1);
  $(this).parent().siblings().stop().fadeTo(300, 1);
});
```